# BeautifulSoup, Recursively Address A Tag with String Argument

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.5

Assuming my XML is as below:

```
<a>
    <b>Some</b>
    <c>Content</c>
    <d>Here</d>
</a>
<a>
    <b>Some2</b>
    <c>Content</c>
    <d>Here</d>
</a>
<a>
    <b>Some3</b>
    <c>Content</c>
    <d>Here</d>
</a>
```

I can fortunately access all `b` tags by `soup.find_all("b")`. However, I need to do specify this recursively, like saying `b tag which is child of a tag`. I must address fully. I tried the things below:

```
soup.find_all("a").find_all("b")
# raises: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_all'

soup("a")("b")
# raises: 'ResultSet' object is not callable
```

How can I fully address a tag? And I must do this by giving string type argument. I do not want a method as below:

```
soup.a.b
```

### Environment

- python 3.5.1
- beautifulsoup 4.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS selector, for example, to select `<b>` element that is direct child of `<a>` :

```
>>> soup.select("a > b")
[<b>Some</b>, <b>Some2</b>, <b>Some3</b>]
```